# Why *remedy* means school term break?

Tags: word-usage

From m-w.com :

Definition of remedy (Entry 1 of 2)
1: a medicine, application, or treatment that relieves or cures a disease
2: something that corrects or counteracts
3: the legal means to recover a right or to prevent or obtain redress for a wrong

I don't understand why it means the break in a school term?

However, what I read from a school's handbook is:

```
Term dates 2021-22

2021 Autumn Term
Friday 3 September - Thursday 16 December
Remedy: Monday 18 October - Friday 29 October; Monday 6 December

2022 Spring term
Thursday 6 January - Friday 25 March
Remedy : Thursday 6 January; Monday 14 - Friday 18 February

2022 Summer Term
Thursday 21 April - Thursday 7 July
Remedy: Monday 2 May; Monday 30 May - Friday 3 June
```

Why Remedy can be a school term's break?

Comment: I've never heard "remedy" used to mean a break in a school term.

Comment: Where is this school?  Maybe "remedy" is a local term.  *Added:*  OED says this is currently used only at two schools: Winchester and St Paul's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://www.oed.com) [subscription required]

> **remedy**, *n*
> ...
> 5. At certain English schools (latterly only Winchester and St Paul's): a time specially granted for recreation; a day's or half-day's holiday.

*Remedy*, with this meaning, has examples back to around 1450.